# Is it preferable to run an application install locally or over network?

Tags: windows-7, filesystems, lan

I have an application that I want to install and the installation file is on a network location on our LAN. There are several users who also need to run this installation.

Is it better for me to copy the installation locally and then run the install or simply run it from it's network location?

I'm asking this because I'm thinking there may be file-locking or performance issues with running it from the network.

Comment: Is it a single file installer exe, or a setup.exe + msi, or a full setup folder (e.g. copied from a CD/DVD)?

Comment: What installer type is it? InstallShield, MSI, NullSoft etc

Comment: The installer is an MSI file

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the network speed, especially if the file is large and reliability (ie the network link going down halfway through the install) will factor in to this.

Otherwise, generally speaking, Windows treats network resources as local in most cases so in that regard there really shouldn't be much of a down side to running the file from a network resource.

Also, if local disk is limited that would be another good reason to install from a network share.

Answer (score -1):

What you said is correct
&
When you run it from network, it first get the data it need to ram and then starts to run it.
So at first it does not differ, but if the file is to big, it try to load a part and then another part and ... .

So it seems if your file is big, copy it.

If your file is small, run it directly.

Comment: Could whoever down-voted this please put a comment as to what's wrong with the answer - it seems fair enough to me...

Comment: Well, you could upvote it ;p